# Is there a difference between a consensus PCR and a pan PCR?

Tags: pcr

I know that a multiplex PCR uses multiple sets of primers in one reaction to amplify multiple targets.

But what is a PCR called that uses generic primers to amplify multiple targets? Is this a consensus PCR? Or a pan PCR? Or do those two terms refer to the same thing?

What about a PCR that uses degenerate primers?

Thank you for your help.